# How can I find out which certificate was used to sign a PKCS7 message?

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, certificate, pkcs#7

I'm using the `System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.SignedCms` class in the .NET framework to read and validate signed data.

For this I have a list of valid certificates that I'm passing in the `CheckSignature` method.

This works great and the method will throw an exception if the signing certificate is not contained in the list.

However I would like to retrieve the exact certificate that was used to validate the message. The `CheckSignature` method returns void and the `Certificates` property on `SignedCms` is always `null` in my data set.

I do not want to brute force all possible certificates, especially as the method will throw me an exception if the certificate is invalid and there can be a lot of certificates in the list.

Any idea how to do this?

**Related question:** Is there a method to check the certificate that will not cause an exception if there is no valid certificate found (I would prefer a boolean return value).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [`SignerInfos`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.pkcs.signedcms.signerinfos%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property, and see if you can extract certificates using the `SignerInfo` objects returned by it.

Comment: Okay, I found it! It IS contained in SignerInfos, but it's a bit complicated. You have to check the SignerIdentifier and cast the contained "Value" to an appropriate type, which in my case was X509IssuerSerial. This object than contains the Issuer distinguished name and the serial number of the certificate, which are unique and can be used to do the lookup.